# Textured text in Actionscript

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, actionscript

There is any way to make a text "textured" - with a result similar to this: http://www.entheosweb.com/fireworks/patterned_text.asp

In Flex (so using AS3)?

I though it was a simple issue, but I'm stuck: i'm googling it from days and was not able to find aa way or workaround to do it...

Answer (score 3):

The rough idea is this:

- Create a TextField with whatever font you need, and write whatever text you want in there.
- Create a new BitmapData object and `draw()` the TextField so that you get a bitmap representation of it.
- Get your texture as a BitmapData object (if you load in a jpg, it'll be in the Bitmap that you get after it's loaded)
- Create a new BitmapData object and use `copyPixels()` to draw your texture, while using the first BitmapData object (the blitted TextField) as an alpha mask: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/BitmapData.html#copyPixels()
- Voila, textured text.

Let me know if you need some code, but it should be pretty straightforward

**Edit with code:**

```
package  
{
    import flash.display.Bitmap;
    import flash.display.BitmapData;
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.geom.Point;
    import flash.geom.Rectangle;
    import flash.text.TextField;
    import flash.text.TextFieldAutoSize;
    import flash.text.TextFormat;

    public class TestTexturedText extends Sprite
    {
        private var m_text:TextField        = null;         // the TextField that we use to write our text
        private var m_texture:BitmapData    = null;         // the texture that we're going to texture our TextField with
        private var m_textBMD:BitmapData    = null;         // the BitmapData that we use to draw our TextField
        private var m_drawPoint:Point       = new Point;    // Point used in drawing the final BitmapData
        private var m_drawRect:Rectangle    = new Rectangle;// the Rectangle we use to determine which part of the texture to take

        // the texture we're using
        [Embed(source="texture.jpg")]
        private var m_textureImage:Class;

        public function TestTexturedText() 
        {
            this._createText( "Trebuchet Ms", 50.0 );   // create our textfield
            this._getTexture();                         // get our texture

            // create textured text 1
            var bmd:BitmapData = this.getTexturedText( "hello world" );
            var b:Bitmap = new Bitmap( bmd );
            b.x = 250.0;
            b.y = 50.0;
            this.addChild( b );

            // create textured text 2
            bmd = this.getTexturedText( "testing" );
            b = new Bitmap( bmd );
            b.x = 250.0;
            b.y = 100.0;
            this.addChild( b );
        }

        /**
         * Get a BitmapData of the text we want, textured
         * @param text The text we're looking at
         * @param randomPos Should we take a random position from our text, or just start at (0,0)?
         * @return A BitmapData object containing our textured text
         */
        public function getTexturedText( text:String, randomPos:Boolean = true ):BitmapData
        {
            // set the text
            this.m_text.text    = text;
            var tw:int          = int( this.m_text.width + 0.5 ); // quick conver to int without clipping
            var th:int          = int( this.m_text.height + 0.5 );

            // reuse our previous BitmapData if we can, rather than always creating a new one
            if ( this.m_textBMD == null || this.m_textBMD.width < tw || this.m_textBMD.height < th )
                this.m_textBMD = new BitmapData( tw, th, true, 0x00000000 );
            else
                this.m_textBMD.fillRect( this.m_textBMD.rect, 0x00000000 ); // clear the bitmapdata of the old rendering

            // draw our text
            this.m_textBMD.draw( this.m_text, null, null, null, null, true );

            // set our draw rect position
            this.m_drawRect.x       = ( randomPos ) ? Math.random() * ( this.m_texture.width - tw ) : 0.0;
            this.m_drawRect.y       = ( randomPos ) ? Math.random() * ( this.m_texture.height - tw ) : 0.0;
            this.m_drawRect.width   = tw;
            this.m_drawRect.height  = th;

            // get a new bitmap data (that we'll return) and copy our pixels, using the first bmd as an alpha mask
            var ret:BitmapData = new BitmapData( tw, th, true, 0x00000000 );
            ret.copyPixels( this.m_texture, this.m_drawRect, this.m_drawPoint, this.m_textBMD, this.m_drawPoint );
            return ret;
        }

        // creates the TextField that we'll use to write our text
        private function _createText( font:String, size:Number ):void
        {
            var tf:TextFormat               = new TextFormat( font, size );
            this.m_text                     = new TextField;
            this.m_text.defaultTextFormat   = tf;
            this.m_text.autoSize            = TextFieldAutoSize.LEFT;

            // debug add it to the stage
            this.m_text.x = 250.0;
            this.addChild( this.m_text );
        }

        // gets the texture that we'll use to create our text
        private function _getTexture():void
        {
            this.m_texture = ( ( new this.m_textureImage ) as Bitmap ).bitmapData;

            // debug add it to the stage
            var debug:Bitmap = new Bitmap( this.m_texture );
            debug.scaleX = debug.scaleY = 0.2;
            this.addChild( debug );
        }

    }

}
```

Some points:

- It'll take a minor bit of work to turn it into a class - this is a main class (as in I use it to run the application)
- Edit the `m_textureImage` embed to point to the texture you want to use, or alternatively, load one in.
- Just call the function `getTexturedText()` to get a BitmapData with the text that you want
- You can remove where I add the different items (texture, textfield, result) to the stage. That's just to show you what's going on
- This is pure AS3, but it'll also work in flex

Comment: Thanks for the answer - I'm a bit confused however sorry: are you referring to Flash I suppose, not Flex (as I don't see any TextField  element in Flex i.e. but mx:Label or mx:Text etc.)?

Answer (score 1):

It's been a while since I used ActionScript, but I could give some ideas.

- Simplest solution I can think of is that you can load an image in a sprite and then mask it using another sprite which has embedded text.
- Other option, more difficult, is to render text as shapes by manually defining each letter as points. Then you could use Papervision3D to texture these shapes. I have not used Papervision3D before but as any other game engine allows texturing this should be possible.

Comment: +1 for masking solution, but -1 for recommending a long-dead open-source 3D engine which is not only no longer being developed but also hugely overkill for this situation. If one is going to draw the letters as bezier curves, a simple bitmap fill is a far superior solution.

Comment: You are right. Papervision3d is an overkill in this case and Bitmap fill would suffice the purpose.

Answer (score 0):

As others have answered, using the text as a mask for an image is how this can be achieved in Flash or Flex.

The answer by divillysausages is a good one, but since you comment there that you are confused by the absence of Flex markup in that example, here is a minimal example in MXML markup:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<mx:Application creationComplete="img.mask=txt" xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml">
    <mx:Canvas>
        <mx:Text id="txt" cacheAsBitmap="true" fontSize="48" fontWeight="bold" text="LOREM IPSUM" />
        <mx:Image id="img" cacheAsBitmap="true" autoLoad="true" source="http://farm3.static.flickr.com/2783/4092743591_3fb90fa599.jpg" />
    </mx:Canvas>
</mx:Application>
```

The principle is the same as in the other answers, the text has to be a bitmap to be used as a mask for the image (here achieved by cacheAsBitmap="true").