# Applying Texture to the Movieclip

Tags: actionscript-3

Here i am looking to apply the texture to the  Text and Movie Clip dynamically.is this possible to do?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple way to do this is to embed the font, create a texture and set the text field as the mask for the texture bitmap:

```
package {
    import flash.display.*;
    import flash.text.*;

    /**
     * @author george
     */
    public class MaskText extends Sprite {
        FontClass_123ffed0d5f76880;
        FontClass_123ffed0d5f76880_arial;

        public function MaskText() {
            init();
        }
        private function init():void{
            //make text
            var tf:TextField = new TextField();
            tf.defaultTextFormat = new TextFormat('arial',32);
            tf.embedFonts = true;
            tf.border = false;
            tf.selectable = false;
            tf.text = "TEXT";
            //make texture
            var tex:BitmapData = new BitmapData(tf.textWidth, tf.textHeight,false,0);
            tex.perlinNoise(110, 110, 32, 64, true, true, 7);
            //create bitmap and apply mask
            var b:Bitmap = new Bitmap(tex);
            b.mask = tf;
            addChild(b);
            addChild(tf);
        }
    }
}
```

There was a pretty similar question on Stackoverflow. Check out other solutions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7240089/textured-text-in-actionscript).

Answer (score 0):

you can use [`beginBitmapFill()`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/Graphics.html#beginBitmapFill%28%29)